# Onclick cell change value with Multiple Dynamic Tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, cell

[jsfiddle.net file](http://jsfiddle.net/waH5S/1/)

```
$(document).ready($(function change_cell_content() {
            $("td").on("click",
                function(){
                    var $cell_id_ref = $(this).attr('cellID');
                    var $table_id_ref = $(this).parent().parent().parent().attr('tableID');
                    var newValue;

                    var currentValue = document.querySelector('[cellID="' + $cell_id_ref + '"]').innerHTML;
                    alert(currentValue);

                    var changeValue = prompt("Enter a new value. (Current " + currentValue + ")");
                    if ( changeValue!==null ) {
                        newValue = changeValue;
                        document.querySelector('[cellID="' + $cell_id_ref + '"]').innerHTML = newValue;
                    }
                });
        }));
```

The first table works perfectly, the other three do not.

Click on any cell. An alert will show the `tableID` of what you clicked on.  A prompt will popup and ask for a new value(stating a current value in the prompt).  This is the problem, the `currentValue` variable is only getting from the first table even though I am using `cellID($cell_id_ref)` and `tableID($table_id_ref)` to attempt to direct it to other tables.

Any help or comments would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your code and make use of jQuery instead of `querySelectorAll`:

```
$(function change_cell_content() {
    $("td").on("click", function () {

        var cell_id_ref = $(this).attr('cellID');
        var $table = $(this).closest('table');
        var newValue;

        var currentValue = $(this).html();
        alert(currentValue);

        var changeValue = prompt("Enter a new value. (Current " + currentValue + ")");
        if (changeValue !== null) {
            $table.find('[cellID="' + cell_id_ref + '"]').text(changeValue);
        }
    });
});
```

You problem was in this line:

```
document.querySelector('[cellID="' + $cell_id_ref + '"]').innerHTML = ...
```

You should select a cell in current table, however above code always selects the first cell from the first table.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/waH5S/3/

Comment: Thank you very much for your help dfsq! I cannot +1 yet, but I certainly will once I can!